# I want to update only date when data comes to mysql

Tags: mysql, arduino, wamp, rfid

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_attendance` (
  `att_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rfid_uid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `punch_time` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

This is working fine with timestamp but i want to take only date and time separately in 2 columns. In one there will be only date and in other there will be time.
I am working on arduino attendance system when an rfid picks a card and entering the attendance it should mark date and time separately not like timestamp
Thanks

Comment: Then you'll have to update the columns explicitly in your code. Only `TIMESTAMP` can use `ON UPDATE` for automatic updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `TIMESTAMP` columns can use the `ON UPDATE` feature to automatically update.

If you're using MySQL 5.7 you can add [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) that hold the date and time.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_attendance` (
  `att_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rfid_uid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `punch_timestamp` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  punch_date DATE AS (DATE(punch_timestamp)),
  punch_time TIME AS (TIME(punch_timestamp))
)
```